# MySQL Is Strictly Equal to Operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, equals

In many programming languages there is the basic equals operator which will see if the text of two strings are equal:

```
if ("Hi" == "hi") {
  //this code runs
}
```

But there is also the strict equal to operator:

```
if ("Hi" === "hi") {
  //this code will never run
}
```

Is there an equivalent operator for the above code snippet in MySQL? The `=` operator just doesn't cut it. If I run:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'john';
```

MySQL will return rows with a `John`, with a capital "J".

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Equality check in strings is usually case-insensitive in SQL.

Comment: What you want is a case sensitive collation. Read this: [Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL case sensitive string comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/mysql-case-sensitive-string-comparison)

Comment: For performance comparison, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/26455492/632951

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `COLLATE` operator to convert the column to a case-sensitive collation:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'john' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) on case sensitivity.

Comment: Hmm... my table collation is set to `latin1_swedish_ci`. I'm getting this error when running the above code sample `#1253 - COLLATION 'latin1_general_cs' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`

Comment: Try `utf8_bin`  collation then.

Comment: Yes, I tried those, with no avail. Here is the SQL to create the table I am using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( /* Some columns, indexes, and primary keys */ ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: There's no way you have latin1_swedish_ci for your UTF8 character set either. It's important to note the difference between LIKE and = here also. When using `=`, it ignores trailing spaces for the comparison, whereas LIKE doesn't ignore trailing spaces. LIKE is more strict and may be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `STRCMP` :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE STRCMP(name, 'john') = 0;
```

Note :

- 0 = same
- -1 = first element smaller
- 1 = first element bigger

You **must** use COLLATES **if you're using MySQL 4.0+ (STRCMP is no longer case sensitive)** :

- `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` = case insensitive (ci)
- `COLLATE utf8_general_cs` = case sensitive (cs)

Comment: This cannot use any indices, though.

Comment: `SELECT  STRCMP('John', 'john') ;` returns `0` in my machine.

Comment: Right, just saw this function use the fields collates, then we still must specify `COLLATE utf8_general_cs`

Comment: `SELECT  STRCMP('John', 'john' COLLATE utf8_bin);` happily returns `-1` :) And so does `SELECT  STRCMP('John' COLLATE utf8_bin, 'john');`

Comment: Ow, I found ! STRCMP **was** case sensitive (before MySQL 4.0)

Comment: Ah... that might explain why I was getting some wacky results. Thanks anyway!