# If MYSQL is case insensitive,How does it works for the Password field in Login?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I was wondering in case of normal select operation the search is case insenesitive.
So `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = aBc` will also consider name with values ABC,abc,abC etc

but in case of login function we just do 
`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE password = aBc`
will be case sensitive and only consider password with aBc value.

How does this happens?I didnt found anything about this in my searches.

Please care to explain.

Thanx All.

Comment: If you save passwords as hashes it won't matter. And that is how you should do it.

Comment: saving password as plaintext? ... that was good one

Comment: No @quarry not that I was just wondering how does that works?

Comment: `password` column probably has a different `COLLATE` sequence/setting. See the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/mysql-case-sensitive-string-comparison. But you shouldn't save passwords as plain text.

Comment: @techie_28 case-sensitivity depends on type of column and collation.

Comment: @juergend thats right I save them as a hash but this is from when I was just a newbie and didnt knew much of hashes.

Comment: @quarry I dont remember defining any collation on the password coloumn ever.I always had made them like all the others.

Comment: this is because encryption functions which you are using are case sensitive.

Comment: @Omesh I am not using any encryption functions.My question is that it works as case insensitive in the first case and as a case sensitive when I use where password ='abC'.Collation of all columns is latin1_swedish_ci.

Comment: that`s weird. try changing column name from password to name or something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it depends on collation of columns, default database collation in MySQL `utf8_general_ci` where `ci` at the end stands for case insensitive.

case sensitive passwords will work only if you are storing passwords in encrypted format using `MD5` or `PASSWORD` function.

```
show variables like '%collation%';
+---------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value             |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection      | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database        | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_server          | latin1_swedish_ci |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: but still it behaves as Case Sensitive even if I havent encrypted passwords to hashes.

Comment: Thanx @Omesh I think that explains it very well and suits my test cases.

Answer (score 4):

$sql="SELECT * FROM user where username='$username' AND BINARY password='$password'";

Answer (score 3):

for case-sensitive use (BINARY)

> SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE **BINARY** password = aBc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the answer to your exact question is, however if you're storing passwords in a database as text, then that is a VERY bad idea. What you should do instead is hash the password upon registration and store it in your database in that form. Then each time a user attempts to login, you rehash the submitted password and compare it to the hash stored in the row with the matching username. Since the hash IS case-sensitive, this solves your problem while adding a much needed level of security.

Answer (score 1):

In many implementations passwords or their hashes are compared in the application server so the problem does not arise.