# SQL Query is not checking case sensitively

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a system to validate a user's username and password.
I am currently have issues with checking the user name...
If someone's username is say, Burrito, when I pass the query to see if it is in the database, it will not check if the case of the letters is correct.
Example:
Username is Michael
They can enter michael or MiChAeL and it will still think it is the same username.

here is what I am using to check the username:

```
$isValid = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM " . getSQL_Info(3) . " WHERE username = '" . $user . "'");
```

Thank you for your time and help.
Also, if you see any problems with my code, if something could be better or what not, please tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you are using deprecated mysql functions
- be aware of security
- the solution of your problem is

  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (BINARY username="someNaMe")

Comment: Thanks!
Not to bother you, but is it possible that you could explain to be a bit more of the deprecated function, I see that there is this PDO::query which from what I can tell replaced mysql_query().
Thanks.
I would just like to know what the '->' means on the manual page for this function, I have looked many places and I am unable to find a suitable explanation.

Comment: sorry, but you found the answer but yourself :) pdo or mysqli replaced the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: the arrow in oop (object oriented programming) is needed to call methods (defined for that object..). But this covers a huge topic :D

Comment: @MichaelMitchell: take a look here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/

Comment: Hey, on last thing, I have updated my functions and all, but now when I enter something like:
`$con->query("SELECT username FROM table WHERE username='". $user ."'");`
It will always return true even if the $user does not exist in the database. Is there a way to make it return false if the specified username does not exist?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You need to check your MySQL encoding type. If it is `utf8_general_ci` or `latin1_swedish_ci` (or anything ending in `_ci`) it is case insensitive.

You could work around this by changing you table encoding or using:

```
SELECT username FROM table WHERE BINARY username = :username
```

I would recommend the forma.

Related: [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/mysql-case-sensitive-string-comparison)

> Also, if you see any problems with my code, if something could be
>   better or what not, please tell me :)

- You are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions

  - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
  - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- I can't see any escaping in your code

Comment: Make the decision server-wide, so change the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use Collate to compare case sensitive strings. Here is a link to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)