# how to search for exact string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what is the Ruby code equivalent to following mysql query?  I'm trying to search for an exact match of a string eg.'MAIN' and 'Main' should be treat different.

```
SELECT UserID FROM sys_users WHERE BINARY UserID='MAIN'
```

Comment: What gem are you using for searching(thinking sphinx/sunspot solar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just like:

```
SysUser.select('UserID').where('BINARY UserID=?', 'MAIN')
```

Answer (score 0):

A very quick look at [ActiveRecord guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) gives the answer:

> 2.1 Pure String Conditions If you’d like to add conditions to your find, you could just specify them in there, just like
>   `Client.where("orders_count = '2'")`. This will find all clients where
>   the orders_count field’s value is 2.

You could have easily found this through google...

Also, case sensitivity is not Rails [responsibility but depends on your database settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql). Hint: You should switch default collation to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby code equivalent to mysql query:

```
SysUser.where("UserID='MAIN'").select('UserID')
```