# Differentiate between two strings with different case in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Consider the following sql command run in MySQL command prompt-

```
select 'aBc'='Abc';
```

O/P

```
+-------------+
| 'aBc'='Abc' |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
```

I expected the result to show '0' in place of '1'.

How can I differentiate between two strings if they are not in the same case?

Comment: Check this question: "
How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?
" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a binary collation. For example:

```
select 'aBc'='Abc' collate utf8_bin;
```

Or you can transform one of the strings into a binary type:

```
select binary('aBc')=binary('Abc');
```

For the differences between these two, see [The _bin and binary Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-binary-collations.html) in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: showing error-
`ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'` for the 1st command. 2nd one runs fine.

Comment: If your client charset is set to `latin1` you can use `latin1_bin`, which is the binary collation that corresponds to the `latin1` charset.

Comment: thanx for navigating me with proper concept.

Answer (score 1):

By default, MySQL is case-insensitive.
Either change column collation, or use `COLLATE` keyword, like:

```
SELECT 'abc' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' = 'abc' COLLATE 'utf8_bin'
```

Comment: It's a character set dependent answer. In my system its throwing an error-
`ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'`

Answer (score 0):

### Command1

```
select BINARY 'aBc'='Abc';
```

### O/P

```
+---------------------+
| BINARY 'aBc'= 'Abc' |
+---------------------+
|                   0 |
+---------------------+
```

### Command2

```
select BINARY 'aBc'= 'aBc';
```

### O/P

```
+---------------------+
| BINARY 'aBc'= 'aBc' |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
+---------------------+
```