# username should be unique if present in database then return error

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project and I want to check the log in credential according to user. When a new user comes and it is log in, then if username present in database then produce an error !

```
username exist
```

**Code:**

```
include('connect.php'); 

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '". $user_name ."' "); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
    { 
     echo 'Username already in use please try another.'; 
    }
    else{
    $opt=$obj->addStudent($user_name,$user_pass,$user_email,$user_contact);
    }
}
```

I want to check ignore case sensitive also.

Comment: ok...i read what u wrote...now... **whats your question** ???

Comment: Read about SQL Injection also... - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: also, `mysql_` is history...read about `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql this might help

Comment: convert case both sides before you test.

Comment: Why dont you just set `username` to unique?

Answer (score 1):

```
include('connect.php'); 

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UPPER(user_name) = '". mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($user_name)) ."' "); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
    { 
     echo 'Username already in use please try another.'; 
    }
    else{
    $opt=$obj->addStudent($user_name,$user_pass,$user_email,$user_contact);
    }
}
```

this way username :XyZ will be same as xyz

Comment: logically this answer is correct...but your solution is immensely prone to `sql injection` ...be aware!! :)

Comment: i m 100% agree but i was just answering owner has to apply sanitation on string

Comment: @NoobEditor injuction part solved some how

Comment: OP will have to decide on what kind of security is needed in the code.... `mysql_` is still insecure but yes does the job of answering OP's question!! :)

Answer (score 0):

use the faster code for you unique name test.

```
include('connect.php'); 

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `user_name` FROM users WHERE LOWER(user_name) = LOWER(". $user_name .")"); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
    { 
     echo 'Username already in use please try another.'; 
    }
    else{
    $opt=$obj->addStudent($user_name,$user_pass,$user_email,$user_contact);
    }
```

Comment: and how is this "faster"???

Comment: its mil-second difference for select * and select column name to whether match or not match.