# php login, i can login even i enter uppercased password or vice versa

Tags: php

i have this code in my login, then i tried to input my password for example my real password is "Reymar25", but when i enter "reymar25" it logins, it should not proceed in the other page. , please help me to resove this.. THANK You

```
<?php

include('dbconnection.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];$password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1");

    //("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password =       '".$password."' LIMIT 1"); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        header("Location: index1.php"); // Modify to go to the page you would like 
        exit; 
    }
    else
    { 
        header("Location: loginform.php"); 
        echo "Please Check Username or Password!";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Ahhhh Noooooo you are storing your password as pain text!

Comment: Aside from the gaping security hole, are you using a case-insensitive character set (ending in _ci) in that table?

Comment: Moreover all passwords should be crypted. At least by md5

Comment: @P0ZiTR0N, md5 is as bad as plain text

Comment: Sir i dont use any encryption function, i just want to compare the value of input password and the password from the database, because uppercase and lowercase characters is my problem,

Answer (score 2):

Check the collation settings of your username and password columns. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

(And please read the comments on your question, they contain important information on how to address other issues with your code)

Answer (score 0):

About the question:

Why do you repeat the SQL statement two times?
The query is however correct. I think you probably need to make columns case sensitive. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql) answer.

---

The mechanism you implement however, is a very weak:

1. One can use SQL injection.
2. You store passwords in plain text, if one
   hacks your server, he/she can hack all the passwords out of it, you
   should use hashes. You can for instance use the username as the salt to generate a hash and then check if the hash exists somewhere in your database.
3. You only delegate your page when the user enters the correct password. In order to make a website safe, you should check the password **each time** in the header of **each page** that should be protected.

Comment: Sir i am not familiar with encryption in PHP, may you teach me on what proper encryption and decryption process should i use?

Comment: You should not encrypt/decrypt. But calculate a hash. That is a function that takes as input username and password and returns a long binary code. The code is not reversible. Thus even if they capture hashes, they can perhaps login, but don't know the password. I think this page offers a good introduction: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code and it works. sorry if i am not using PDO,

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
if(strcmp($username,$row['username'])==0 && strcmp($password,$row['password'])==0)
{

header("Location: index1.php");

}
else
{
echo "Somethings wrong either on your Username or Password Please Try Again" ;
}
}
```

}
   ?>