# SugarCrm create custom module without Studio

Tags: module, sugarcrm

I am building a custom module for Sugar v.6.5.16. This module works with data of other modules so my module does not need database table, I do not want beens, not importable, I actually do not want anything. I have my own controller, own classes, etc and end of the story. It works. Now I want to create an installable package and NO, I DO NOT WANT TO MAKE A PACKAGE IN STUDIO. I have become quite frustrated because everyone suggests to create the package in studio where it is obbligatory to select a type(basic, company, etc) which will add data structure, bean, db table - which is really handsome but I do not want all that stuff. I actually made a test package with studio and I removed all bean info from manifest file and killed vardefs content and I managed to install it but then my module does not get listed in the "module=Administration&action=ConfigureTabs".

So, the question is what do i put where to be able to see my module listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check link
http://techs.studyhorror.com/sugarcrm-manually-create-custom-modules-i-95

Create custom module in sugarcrm is not a good approach so avoid this process, as per understanding coding and logic for sugarcrm development practice is good to create module from custom code.

Comment: thanks I looked at that tut and got some good ideas from it - still, developing for sugar seems to be a nightmare

Comment: That article has no publication date and does not specify a SugarCRM version. How old is it?

Answer (score 5):

Old post, but I think this page is really worth reading: http://alanstorm.com/sugar_crm_hello_world.

Excellent example of minimal module coding without studio and at the same time a very nice introduction to Sugar logic.

Comment: That article is *the* best I have seen in describing clearly how the MVC and routing works in SugarCRM. It is well worth a read, and all the examples given work in an incremental way. IMO *this* is the exact answer to the question - create a "hello world" module with no database dependency in just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

i Do agree with Rupesh shingh Create custom module fully in sugarcrm is not a good approach until and unless u understand the complete flow !

for understanding the flow you can go through this :-

1)understand controller,views and how it we can use it 
[Hello module](http://alanstorm.com/category/sugarcrm#sugarcrm_for_php_developers)
And try to complete 2-3 chapter of this book definitive guide by John Mertic

2)create costume module from studio and first try to do **customization** with **edit** and **detail view** 
[Flow how customize edit and details view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340660/prevent-duplicate-value-using-ajax-in-sugar-crm)

3)After this try to customize list view based on condition and try to customize additional details popup [add where clause default listview](http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/02/28/add-where-clause-for-listview-data-in-sugarcrm/)  try to create you own list view [Add custom button in list view to overwrite the list view search](https://suitecrm.com/forum/developer-help/2743-add-custom-button-in-list-view-to-overwrite-the-list-view-search)

4)go through **chapter 10** of  definitive guide by John Mertic which shows how to create **custom module** with out creating package in studio **( manually )** !

I hope this will help !!!