# Custom validation for unique custom field

Tags: suitecrm

I'm trying to do a custom validation.
I have a module in which there is a field that must be unique, so suitecrm must not allow you to create two records with that same field.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to validate the sic_code Field in the Accounts module.

Following example was tested in SuiteCRM 7.11.2 using the Extension framework.

Go create a file in the `custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/Vardefs` folder.

You can name the file `sugarfield_sic_code.php`.

Inside of the file add this example snippet:

```
  $dictionary['Account']['fields']['sic_code']['validation']= array (
  'type' => 'callback',
  'callback' => 'function(formname,nameIndex){alert("validating"+formname); return false;}',
);
```

Now make sure sic_code is inside the editview (duh) and when you click SAVE you will be shown the alert + an error message below the field (in red)

That is the overall idea.

If you need something more elaborated doing Ajax, some templating, there is a great answer here on SO (for sugarcrm but should work for Suite)

[prevent duplicate value using ajax in sugar crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340660/prevent-duplicate-value-using-ajax-in-sugar-crm)

Comment: I tried the method described on the page but for suitecrm it doesn't work

Comment: that ajax codes is possible to implement on more than 1 criteria? like you are going to check if name, last name and mobile number if already exist?