# Include .js file in SuiteCRM (v. >7) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm new in SuiteCRM world. I'm trying to include a new .js file in a module but it seems doesn't work.

I seen that in Sugar version 6.5 for include a .js file it's enough to do something like that

```
$viewdefs[$module_name]['EditView']['templateMeta']['includes'] =
array (
    array (
        'file' => 'modules/demo_demo_form/demo.js',
    ),

);
```

I also read that in the newer version(7>) it's changed the way to include a .js file.

I tried different ways* but seems doesn't work.

```
 $js_groupings[$module_name]['modules/demo_demo_form/demo.js'] = 
 'include/modules/demo_demo_form/demo.js';
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my previous answer to another similar question will [help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141324/custom-validation-for-unique-custom-field/55155159#55155159)

First, include your custom JS in the `editviewdefs.php` (example for Accounts module)

```
'includes' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'file' => 'modules/Accounts/Account.js',
          'file' => 'custom/modules/Accounts/myCustomFile.js',
        ),
      ),
```

Create the custom JS file `custom/modules/Accounts/myCustomFile.js` .

```
function yourCustomFunction(formElement){
  console.log(formElement); 
}
```

Then update the field you want to monitor for changes (contractsigned_c in the example) using the following code in the editviewdefs.php:

```
array (
            'name' => 'contractsigned_c',
            'label' => 'LBL_CONTRACTSIGNED',
            'displayParams' =>
             array (
              'updateCallback' => 'yourCustomFunction(this)',
          ),
          ),
```

Now do a `Repair and Rebuild` inside the Admin/Repair section and voilà it should work :)

You can add the JS function on the `function display()` if you want, its the samething, the function will be called right after native `combo update`. It will look like this  `combo_contractsigned_c.update(); yourCustomFunction(this)`

Comment: yes, yesterday I tried again and with this notation 'includes' => array( 0=> ...)' it works fine.