# Add validation to duplicate value in suitecrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm, sugarbean

I want to add a custom validation to first name and last name field to avoid duplicate values i tried following this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340660/prevent-duplicate-value-using-ajax-in-sugar-crm)
but its not working for me. Is there any experts who knows other ways to do this ?