# Replacing where(username: usernames) with case-insensitive finder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I was previously using `where(username: usernames)` to take an array of usernames like and return an ActiveRecord::Relation of users. I've since created an Index on lower(username) and replaced User#find_by_username with the following:

```
def self.find_by_username(username)
  where("lower(username) = ?", username.downcase).first
end
```

This fails:

```
def self.find_by_usernames(usernames)
  where("lower(username) = ?", usernames.map(&:downcase))
end
```

It works when it's an array of one username, but not for multiple usernames. It generates SQL like `"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (lower(username) = 'joshsmith','vendiddy')"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your method as below:

```
def self.find_by_usernames(usernames)
  where("lower(username) in (?)", usernames.map(&:downcase))
end
```

Use `in` instead of `=` because you want to check against multiple values in an array.

Comment: Excellent! I had tried the parens and thought I had tried the `IN`, but guess I was doing something else wrong in the REPL. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer when timeout is over. :)

Comment: Will do. Set a timer. :)

Comment: hehe..surely :D Your time starts now.

Answer (score 0):

Some databases are not set case sensitive on text comparison as a default, like MySQL for example.

```
where("username in (?)", usernames.map(&:downcase))
```

The above delivers the desired result on MySQL unless default has been overwritten. See [this post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

I do agree however that adding the lower function should be the preferred method unless you like to gain a small speed advantage since the database server doesn't have to convert the string first.

```
> Contact.first
Contact Load (172.3ms)  SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` ORDER BY `contacts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Contact id: 1, name: "John"> 

> Contact.where(name: "john")
Contact Load (171.9ms)  SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`name` = 'john'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Contact id: 1, name: "John"]> 

> Contact.where(name: "JOHN")
Contact Load (172.3ms)  SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`name` = 'JOHN'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Contact id: 1, name: "John"]>
```

Comment: Kirti's answer is more appropriate because it keeps in mind the index I have on `lower(username)`, but generally, yes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - will keep in mind. Was meant to be an answer - removing the 'question style' line.