# PHP SQL login case sensitive

Tags: php, networking, authentication

I am learning out to do website log-in and create creation. I am facing the probably where my script does not check if the two strings are the same case. 
Example, Foo and foO return both true.

My current PHP script is:

```
//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thank you... Didn't see that one on Google.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "COLLATE latin1_general_cs" character set to differentiate to upper case or lower case.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `your condiction` COLLATE latin1_general_cs;
```

or you can use

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE BINARY `column` = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the WINDOWS:
you can find the my.ini and change the lower_case_table_names=0.
If you are in the LINUX:
you can find the my.cnf and change the lower_case_table_names=0.

Answer (score 0):

The default collation for character set latin1, which is latin1_swedish_ci, happens to be case-insensitive.

You can choose a case-sensitive collation, for example latin1_general_cs while creating a database schema .
Have look in this link

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15250/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause