# Confusion to display data with 'MA' and 'Ma'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a kind of rarity as to display the data, taking into account the following tables as follows:

```
mysql> describe materiales;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| registro  | int(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| clave     | char(6)      | NO   | UNI |            |                |
| clave2    | char(20)     | YES  | MUL |            |                |
| descr     | char(30)     | YES  |     |            |                |
| descr2    | char(250)    | YES  |     |            |                |
| unidad    | char(7)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| presest   | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| unidadpre | char(7)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| codbar    | char(30)     | YES  |     |            |                |
| impuesto  | double(18,7) | YES  |     | 0.0000000  |                |
| mantpend  | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0          |                |
| grupplat  | char(6)      | YES  | MUL |            |                |
| fechalta  | date         | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| usuarmod  | char(6)      | YES  |     |            |                |
| fechamod  | date         | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+

mysql> describe grupos;
+----------+----------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+----------+----------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| registro | int(12)  | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| clave    | char(6)  | NO   | UNI |            |                |
| descr    | char(30) | YES  |     |            |                |
| fechalta | date     | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| usuarmod | char(6)  | YES  |     |            |                |
| fechamod | date     | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
+----------+----------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

To query where I want to just show me the Ma only the grupplat but shows me the MA and Ma as see bottom:

```
mysql> SELECT CLAVE,DESCR,GRUPPLAT FROM MATERIALES WHERE 
grupplat>='MA' AND grupplat<='MA' ORDER BY GRUPPLAT;
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
| CLAVE  | DESCR                          | GRUPPLAT |
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
| PE100A | DEDOS QUESO                    | MA       |
| PE125A | FUNKY MONKEY BITES             | MA       |
| PE125B | LUCKY DOG BOGARTS D-LIGHT      | MA       |
| PE125C | ROCKY ROAD PEANUT BUTTER BITES | MA       |
| PE125D | SIRENAS SEAFOOD MEDLEY         | MA       |
| PE200A | HOJA TRANSFER                  | MA       |
| PE250A | FRITURA CHURIS                 | MA       |
| PE271A | HAMBURGUESA AMERICANA RES      | MA       |
| PE271B | HAMBURGUESA AMERICANA JR       | MA       |
| PE275A | PAPA ADOBADA                   | MA       |
| PE301A | PAPA FRANCESA 1-4              | MA       |
| PE304A | PAPA FRANCESA 3-8              | MA       |
| PE308A | PAPA FRANCESA 5-16             | MA       |
| PE312A | PAPA FRITA                     | MA       |
| PE315A | PAPA GAJO NATURAL              | MA       |
| PE335A | PAPA HASH TRIANGULO            | MA       |
| PE370A | POLLO ALITA MARINADA IQF       | MA       |
| PE385A | POLLO NUGGET                   | MA       |
| PE410A | PIZZA BASE                     | MA       |
| PE411A | PIZZA REDONDA DULCE            | MA       |
| PE413A | PIZZA DE ZATAR                 | MA       |
| PE450A | VERDURA CONGELADA MIXTA        | MA       |
| PE510A | WAFLES                         | MA       |
| PF0001 | PRODUCTO FICTICIO              | Ma       | <--- ERROR
| PF0002 | AGUA POTABLE                   | Ma       | <--- ERROR
| PF0003 | AGUA DE GARRAFON               | Ma       | <--- ERROR
| PF0004 | HIELO                          | Ma       | <--- ERROR
| PE250F | FRITURA CAZARES                | MA       |
| PE301H | PAPA FRANCESA 1-2 ONDULADA     | MA       |
| PE510D | WAFFLES                        | MA       |
| PE271C | HAMBURGUESA ARRACHERA 198 G    | MA       |
| PE370B | POLLO ALITAS MARINADAS         | MA       |
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
```

as you can see, but put another query with the following syntax like the following to show only 'Ma' data but... Show me all data of 'Ma' and 'MA'

```
mysql> SELECT CLAVE,DESCR,GRUPPLAT FROM MATERIALES WHERE 
grupplat>='Ma' AND grupplat<='Ma' ORDER BY GRUPPLAT;
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
| CLAVE  | DESCR                          | GRUPPLAT |
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
| PE100A | DEDOS QUESO                    | MA       |
| PE125A | FUNKY MONKEY BITES             | MA       |
| PE125B | LUCKY DOG BOGARTS D-LIGHT      | MA       |
| PE125C | ROCKY ROAD PEANUT BUTTER BITES | MA       |
| PE125D | SIRENAS SEAFOOD MEDLEY         | MA       |
| PE200A | HOJA TRANSFER                  | MA       |
| PE250A | FRITURA CHURIS                 | MA       |
| PE271A | HAMBURGUESA AMERICANA RES      | MA       |
| PE271B | HAMBURGUESA AMERICANA JR       | MA       |
| PE275A | PAPA ADOBADA                   | MA       |
| PE301A | PAPA FRANCESA 1-4              | MA       |
| PE304A | PAPA FRANCESA 3-8              | MA       |
| PE308A | PAPA FRANCESA 5-16             | MA       |
| PE312A | PAPA FRITA                     | MA       |
| PE315A | PAPA GAJO NATURAL              | MA       |
| PE335A | PAPA HASH TRIANGULO            | MA       |
| PE370A | POLLO ALITA MARINADA IQF       | MA       |
| PE385A | POLLO NUGGET                   | MA       |
| PE410A | PIZZA BASE                     | MA       |
| PE411A | PIZZA REDONDA DULCE            | MA       |
| PE413A | PIZZA DE ZATAR                 | MA       |
| PE450A | VERDURA CONGELADA MIXTA        | MA       |
| PE510A | WAFLES                         | MA       |
| PF0001 | PRODUCTO FICTICIO              | Ma       |
| PF0002 | AGUA POTABLE                   | Ma       |
| PF0003 | AGUA DE GARRAFON               | Ma       |
| PF0004 | HIELO                          | Ma       |
| PE250F | FRITURA CAZARES                | MA       |
| PE301H | PAPA FRANCESA 1-2 ONDULADA     | MA       |
| PE510D | WAFFLES                        | MA       |
| PE271C | HAMBURGUESA ARRACHERA 198 G    | MA       |
| PE370B | POLLO ALITAS MARINADAS         | MA       |
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
```

but if the order is for 'group by', for some reason not the 'Ma' appears as

```
mysql> SELECT CLAVE,DESCR,GRUPPLAT FROM MATERIALES group BY grupplat;
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
| CLAVE  | DESCR                          | GRUPPLAT |
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
| AB002A | ACEITE DE CACAHUATE            | M0       |
| AV005A | HUEVO                          | M1       |
| CR005A | CERDO BISTEC                   | M2       |
| EM010A | CERDO CHORIZO                  | M3       |
| ES005A | ACHIOTE                        | M4       |
| FV003A | ACELGA                         | M5       |
| LA010A | CREMA ACIDA                    | M6       |
| PN010A | BISQUET DULCE 30 G             | M7       |
| PA010A | CAPELLINI                      | M8       |
| PM005A | ALMEJA CHIRLA                  | M9       |
| PE100A | DEDOS QUESO                    | MA       |
| PO010A | ACEITE DE AJONJOLI PICANTE     | MB       |
| TT050A | MASA DE MAIZ                   | MC       |
| PT010A | BROWNIE                        | MD       |
| HN010A | HELADO BANANA BLU              | ME       |
| AR005A | AGUA NATURAL 355 ML            | MI       |
| CA010A | CAFE CAREY GOURMET GRANO       | MJ       |
| CO025A | GINSENG AMPOLLETA              | ML       |
| TE005A | TE AMANECER                    | MM       |
| CE010A | BOHEMIA 355 ML                 | MN       |
| AN005A | ANIS CHINCHON DULCE            | MO       |
| BR010A | BRANDY AZTECA DE ORO           | MP       |
| CV070A | CH MOET CHANDON DOM PERIGNON   | MQ       |
| CG010A | COGNAC COURVOISIER V.S.O.P     | MR       |
| CL002A | AGUARDIENTE CACHACA            | MS       |
| GI015A | GINEBRA BEEFEATER              | MT       |
| RO010A | RON APPLETON BLANCO            | MU       |
| TQ010A | MEZ ALIPUS SAN ANDRES          | MV       |
| VO020A | VODKA ABSOLUT                  | MW       |
| WH010A | WHISKY BALLANTINES FINEST      | MX       |
| VB010A | VB ALBERT BICHOT CHABLIS       | MY       |
| VR050A | VR CERAUSOLO TOSE D ABRUZZO LA | MZ       |
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+
```

in the table of group if i query to see the clave for the groupplat shows me like this:

```
mysql> SELECT registro,clave,descr FROM compras.grupos group by clave;
+----------+-------+----------------------+
| registro | clave | descr                |
+----------+-------+----------------------+
|        3 | M0    | ABARROTES            |
|        4 | M1    | AVES                 |
|        5 | M2    | CARNES ROJAS         |
|        6 | M3    | EMBUTIDOS            |
|        7 | M4    | ESPECIAS-SECOS       |
|        8 | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|        9 | M6    | LACTEOS              |
|       10 | M7    | PANES                |
|       11 | M8    | PASTAS               |
|       12 | M9    | PESCADOS-MARISCOS    |
|       13 | MA    | PRODUCTOS ELABORADOS |
|       14 | MB    | PRODUCTOS ORIENTALES |
|       15 | MC    | TORTILLAS            |
|       16 | MD    | PASTELES             |
|       17 | ME    | HELADOS-NIEVES       |
|       18 | MF    | PRODUCTOS EXOTICOS   |
|       19 | MI    | AGUAS-REFRESCOS      |
|       20 | MJ    | CAFES                |
|       21 | MK    | CHOCOLATES FRAPPES   |
|       22 | ML    | COMPLEMENTOS ALIMENT |
|       23 | MM    | TES                  |
|       24 | MN    | CERVEZAS             |
|       25 | MO    | ANISES               |
|       26 | MP    | BRANDYS              |
|       27 | MQ    | CHAMPAGNES-VINOS ES  |
|       28 | MR    | COGNACS              |
|       29 | MS    | CREMAS-LICORES-OPORT |
|       30 | MT    | GINEBRAS             |
|       31 | MU    | RONES                |
|       32 | MV    | TEQUILAS             |
|       33 | MW    | VODKAS               |
|       34 | MX    | WHISKYS              |
|       35 | MY    | VINOS BLANCOS        |
|       36 | MZ    | VINOS TINTOS         |
|       37 | Ma    | AGREGADOS            |
+----------+-------+----------------------+
```

so... not if I have to change or whether to remove the key 'MUL' of materiales table to see if "solve the problem" because when I do a query of the group 'Ma' no shows... but 'MA' yes... so I'm already quite frustrated that I find this very annoying bug! because i use this another query for to join tables I need to show the user a restaurant with inner join, but I submit this bug because MYSQL as it does not show the Ma ... gets it like MA

```
SELECT * FROM DETOC INNER JOIN MATERIALES ON DETOC.MATERIAL = MATERIALES.CLAVE 
                    INNER JOIN GRUPOS ON MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT = GRUPOS.CLAVE 
                    INNER JOIN ORDENESCOMPRA ON DETOC.ORDCOMP = ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE 
                    INNER JOIN PROVEEDORES ON ORDENESCOMPRA.CVEPROV = PROVEEDORES.CLAVE 
                   INNER JOIN AREAS ON ORDENESCOMPRA.AREA = AREAS.CLAVE 
                    WHERE ORDENESCOMPRA.FECHALTA>='2014-01-01' AND ORDENESCOMPRA.FECHALTA<='2015-01-19' 
                        AND ORDENESCOMPRA.AREA>='    50' AND ORDENESCOMPRA.AREA<='   AF2' 
                        AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CVEPROV>='000004' AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CVEPROV<='011551'
                        AND MATERIALES.CLAVE>='AB002A' AND MATERIALES.CLAVE<='WH420A' 
                        AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT>='M0' AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT<='Ma' 
                        AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE>='8780' AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE<='8790';
```

Comment: what about update them to be the same ?

Comment: You need to change the table to a case-sensitive collation. Otherwise, `MA` and `Ma` are treated as equivalent in comparisons and grouping.

Comment: Try `WHERE 
grupplat COLLATE latin1_general_cs >='MA' AND grupplat COLLATE latin1_general_cs <='MA'`

Comment: it's impossible... because has too much important information and is too complicated to modify all... so... is not an option...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

Comment: This question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5629129/625594 - please check it, it might help you

Answer (score 1):

In a case insensitive database, "MA" and 'Ma' and 'ma' are exactly the same.

If you want them treated differently all the time, you should make the table  or the column or the database case sensitive.  Be aware that this affects much more than you and your particualr query, so be sure of the business requirement and make sure all others who develop for the database are aware of the possible change and fully exercise the database in QA before promoting to prod.

If you only occasionally need case-sensitivity, you can use a collation in the query. But be aware that this will add additional time to your query and you would have to do it to **every** query that needs this case sensitivity. If you need this for all queries, then it must be done inteh database.

In sql server you can aply collation settings to an individual column, I don't knwo if this is possible in mysql though. I also don't know if it is possible to create a view that is case sensitive when the underlying table is not. But it would be worth experimenting with.

Answer (score 0):

ok... i try wit COLLATE latin1_general_cs but this solution dont solve the problem, because when i try this:

```
select detoc.ordcomp, materiales.clave,materiales.descr, grupos.clave,grupos.descr from detoc
                inner join materiales on detoc.material = materiales.clave 
                INNER JOIN GRUPOS ON MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT = GRUPOS.CLAVE 
                INNER JOIN ORDENESCOMPRA ON DETOC.ORDCOMP = ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE 
                INNER JOIN PROVEEDORES ON ORDENESCOMPRA.CVEPROV = PROVEEDORES.CLAVE 
                INNER JOIN AREAS ON ORDENESCOMPRA.AREA = AREAS.CLAVE 
                WHERE ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE>='8781' AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE<='8791'
                AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT COLLATE latin1_general_cs>='M0' AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT COLLATE latin1_general_cs<='Ma';
```

the data show me this:

```
+---------+--------+--------------------------------+-------+----------------------+
| ordcomp | clave  | descr                          | clave | descr                |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------+-------+----------------------+
|    8782 | PN540B | PAN DULCE CROSSAINT CHABACANO  | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN451B | PAN CAMPESINO RUSTICO MINI .06 | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN511A | PAN CHAPATA RUSTICA MINI .060  | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN310C | PAN BAGUET CAMPESINO .060 KILO | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN310D | PAN BAGUET 350 GR              | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN535B | PAN DULCE CONCHA BLANCA .030   | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN535C | PAN DULCE CONCHA CHOCOLATE .03 | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN530B | PAN CHOCOLATIN 30 G            | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN560B | PAN MINI DANES .030            | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PE410A | PIZZA BASE                     | MA    | PRODUCTOS ELABORADOS |
|    8783 | FV007A | AGUACATE HASS EXTRA            | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV421A | JITOMATE GUAJE PARA MOLER      | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV455A | KIWI                           | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV570A | MAMEY                          | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV643A | NARANJA AMARILLA               | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV653B | NOPAL CAMBRAY                  | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV720C | PAPA ALFA GRANDE               | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV725A | PAPA CAMBRAY                   | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV746A | PEPINO                         | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV755B | PIMIENTO ROJO                  | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV755C | PIMIENTO VERDE                 | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV763C | PLATANO TABASCO                | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV124A | CEBOLLIN                       | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV415A | JITOMATE BOLA                  | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV418A | JITOMATE CHERRY                | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV305A | GERMINADO DE ALFALFA           | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV107A | CALABAZA ITALIANA              | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV118B | CEBOLLA BLANCA MEDIANA         | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV122A | CEBOLLA MORADA                 | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV144A | CHILE SERRANO                  | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV136A | CHILE CUARESMENO GRANDE        | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | ES090A | CHILE MORITA                   | M4    | ESPECIAS-SECOS       |
|    8783 | FV147A | CILANTRO                       | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV232A | EPAZOTE                        | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV235B | ESPARRAGO MEDIANO              | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV767A | PORTOBELLO JUMBO               | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV355A | HIERBABUENA                    | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV277A | FRESA DRISCOL                  | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8783 | FV127A | CHAMPINONES JUMBO              | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8784 | AB165D | FRIJOL NEGRO                   | M0    | ABARROTES            |
|    8785 | PN510F | PAN CHAPATA NATURAL 100 GR     | M7    | PANES                |
|    8785 | PN420C | PAN BOLLO NATURAL 100 G        | M7    | PANES                |
|    8786 | FV107A | CALABAZA ITALIANA              | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV418A | JITOMATE CHERRY                | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV277A | FRESA DRISCOL                  | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV355A | HIERBABUENA                    | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV767A | PORTOBELLO JUMBO               | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV235B | ESPARRAGO MEDIANO              | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV147A | CILANTRO                       | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV124A | CEBOLLIN                       | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV890A | UVA VERDE SIN SEMILLA          | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV763A | PLATANO MACHO                  | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV763C | PLATANO TABASCO                | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV725A | PAPA CAMBRAY                   | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV643A | NARANJA AMARILLA               | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV136A | CHILE CUARESMENO GRANDE        | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV144A | CHILE SERRANO                  | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV127A | CHAMPINONES JUMBO              | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV118B | CEBOLLA BLANCA MEDIANA         | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV110A | CAMOTE AMARILLO                | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8786 | FV421A | JITOMATE GUAJE PARA MOLER      | M5    | FRUTAS-VERDURAS      |
|    8787 | AV010A | POLLO PECHUGA DESHUESADA       | M1    | AVES                 |
|    8787 | AV015A | POLLO PECHUGA ENTERA           | M1    | AVES                 |
|    8787 | AV025A | POLLO PIERNA CON MUSLO         | M1    | AVES                 |
|    8787 | AV005A | HUEVO                          | M1    | AVES                 |
|    8788 | LA125C | QUESO CREMA                    | M6    | LACTEOS              |
|    8788 | LA260B | YOGHURT NATURAL                | M6    | LACTEOS              |
|    8788 | LA115C | QUESO COTTAGE                  | M6    | LACTEOS              |
|    8788 | LA080B | MANTEQUILLA                    | M6    | LACTEOS              |
|    8788 | EM100B | PAVO JAMON                     | M3    | EMBUTIDOS            |
|    8788 | LA205A | QUESO PANELA                   | M6    | LACTEOS              |
|    8790 | EM215A | VIENA SALCHICHA                | M3    | EMBUTIDOS            |
|    8790 | LA062B | LECHE ENTERA                   | M6    | LACTEOS              |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------+-------+----------------------+
```

The problem is that no data from 8781 shows that should to show for example if i try this:

```
select detoc.ordcomp, materiales.clave,materiales.descr, grupos.clave,grupos.descr from detoc
                inner join materiales on detoc.material = materiales.clave 
                INNER JOIN GRUPOS ON MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT = GRUPOS.CLAVE 
                INNER JOIN ORDENESCOMPRA ON DETOC.ORDCOMP = ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE 
                INNER JOIN PROVEEDORES ON ORDENESCOMPRA.CVEPROV = PROVEEDORES.CLAVE 
                INNER JOIN AREAS ON ORDENESCOMPRA.AREA = AREAS.CLAVE 
                WHERE ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE>='8781' AND ORDENESCOMPRA.CLAVE<='8782'
                AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT COLLATE latin1_general_cs>='M0' AND MATERIALES.GRUPPLAT COLLATE latin1_general_cs<='MZ';
```

it's show me:

```
+---------+--------+--------------------------------+-------+----------------------+
| ordcomp | clave  | descr                          | clave | descr                |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------+-------+----------------------+
|    8781 | CE010F | BOHEMIA OBSCURA 355 ML R       | MN    | CERVEZAS             |
|    8781 | CE010E | BOHEMIA 355 ML R               | MN    | CERVEZAS             |
|    8781 | CE080C | SOL 355 ML R                   | MN    | CERVEZAS             |
|    8781 | CE085C | TECATE 325 ML R                | MN    | CERVEZAS             |
|    8781 | CE085F | TECATE LIGHT 325 ML R          | MN    | CERVEZAS             |
|    8782 | PN540B | PAN DULCE CROSSAINT CHABACANO  | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN451B | PAN CAMPESINO RUSTICO MINI .06 | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN511A | PAN CHAPATA RUSTICA MINI .060  | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN310C | PAN BAGUET CAMPESINO .060 KILO | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN310D | PAN BAGUET 350 GR              | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN535B | PAN DULCE CONCHA BLANCA .030   | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN535C | PAN DULCE CONCHA CHOCOLATE .03 | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN530B | PAN CHOCOLATIN 30 G            | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PN560B | PAN MINI DANES .030            | M7    | PANES                |
|    8782 | PE410A | PIZZA BASE                     | MA    | PRODUCTOS ELABORADOS |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------+-------+----------------------+
```

so... I ended up ideas ... to change to make it different is very difficult right now because of the magnitude of data !!!!!