# How to search single character word in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am maintaing jobs portal site, in this in search box when user search with single character as 'C' then i want to dislay 'C developer' or 'C programmer' or ' C/C++ Develoepr' like.  But i am getting 'Customer service jobs' and  some other jobs. 
I am using the following query.

```
$qry="select * from tbl_jobs where job_title LIKE 
'".$_REQUEST['job_title']."%' or job_title LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['job_title']."%' ";
```

This query not working properly. Please help me how to display c language related jobs when user searches single word as 'C''

Comment: can you give me the link to the site? The SQL injection possibilities just seem endless. Bobby tables is comming for you!

Comment: i will convert this query to prepare statements. But the problem is search conditions

Comment: Logically, if you search for all jobs including "C" it will also find all jobs with words that have a "c" in it. A possible solution may be to make a case-sensitive search (See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql) for more info). However, in this case I would just say your current search is logical and should not be changed to fit the "C" usecase.

Comment: the query seems ok, apart from the security, however it could be that the collation of the field/table is set to case sensitive. change it to some case insensitive collation as utf8_general_ci  the last two letters stand for that case sensitive/insensitive

Comment: i am not saying about case sensitive. I am saying that when i search with c i am getting some unwanted results(like customer, css, csn) . i want exactly c developer, c programmer, like that

Comment: @venkyrao, no you are not getting unwanted results, you get results that you asked you are looking for all records that contain character `C` in job_title, you can try to find 'C ' <- with space but then you won`t find C++ and C#

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
$qry="select * from tbl_jobs where job_title LIKE 
'%".$_REQUEST['job_title']."%developer%' or job_title LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['job_title']."%programmer%' ";
```

That's the closest thing I can come up with.