# MySQL Username not case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql

sir i have problem on php mysql login

On my db:

```
username = admin 
password = addbcea06efdd20f934b35e3b2111e55
```

1st i test This the query on mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'admin' AND `password` = 'addbcea06efdd20f934b35e3b2111e55'
```

the 1st result is 1

but when i my second test

```
SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'Admin' AND `password` = 'addbcea06efdd20f934b35e3b2111e55'
```

why the result keep 1? This should be 0. I only change the username to capital letter.
What should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MySQL columns can be made IN-case-sensitive by creating them with the binary keyword. I suspect this is your problem. You can modify the column to be binary or change your query to

```
SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE BINARY `username` = 'Admin' AND `password` = 'addbcea06efdd20f934b35e3b2111e55'
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL compares data in a case-insensitive manner except for database, table and column names. That is why your second query didn't return 0.

Comment: Not always true, depends on the server configuration for the charset.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid case-sensitive problems is always to use the php function strtolower() in the two parts of data manipulation: insert and query, in this case in the registration and the login verification.

You can add this line before the registration insert in your code:

```
$username = strtolower ( $username );
```

This will make always the username is stored in lowercase, then you can do the same in the login part of your program. Since you always will be comparing lowercases strings there is no chance of a case-sensitive error.