# join 2 tables case sensitive upper and lower case

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, case-sensitive

I have 2 tables and need to get result on brand code.

In the database i have for example 2 different brands but their code is the same (only difference in lower and upper case). For example:

code   Name
ab     Nike
AB     Adidas

How to inner join 2 tables on code to get this 2 separately?

Right now after inner join i get total sum of this 2.

```
SELECT Code, BrandName, Count(*) QTY, SUM(Price) TOTAL
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Code=B.Code
GROUP BY Code, BrandName
```

This query will give me wrong result as it does not join sensitively on upper and lower case.

Please help :)

Comment: You should define what database engine you're using.

Comment: MS SQL. Sql management studio

Comment: Defining the database would be a good start to help people help you. But I would assume this is a job for collation. Read up on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two quick ways you can solve this.

**1.** You specify a case-sensitive collation (rules for comparing strings across characters in a character set) for A.Code and B.Code. In MySQL and a few other database management systems, the default collation is case-insensitive.

That is, assuming that you're using MySQL or similar, you'll have to modify your statement as such:

```sql
SELECT Code, BrandName, Count(*) QTY, SUM(Price) TOTAL
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Code=B.Code COLLATE latin1_bin
GROUP BY Code, BrandName
```

If, however, you plan on only performing case-sensitive queries on A and B, it may be in your interest to set the default collation on those two tables to case-sensitive.

Please see [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5629111/3800937)

**2.** Cast A.Code and B.Code to a binary string and compare the two. This is an simple way to compare two strings, byte-by-byte, thus achieving case-insensitivity.

```sql
SELECT Code, BrandName, Count(*) QTY, SUM(Price) TOTAL
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON BINARY A.Code=B.Code
GROUP BY Code, BrandName
```

Comment: Changing to BINARY is actually a bad idea, as some collations will compare equal for accented characters, for instance, though the binary form would be different.

Answer (score 7):

Since you use a collation that is case insensitive and want to differentiate on case try using the `collate` keyword with a suitable case-sensitive collation:

```
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Code COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS  = B.Code COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to specify the collation on both sides of the join - it might be enough with `ON A.Code = B.Code COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS`

Comment: Cool, good to know - I haven't used collate that much before.

Answer (score 0):

COLLATE didn't work for me on anything I was trying as the DB was in a utf8 format and wouldn't convert. I was able, however, to use an md5 hash comparison and the md5 function is case-sensitive..

```
INNER JOIN B ON md5(A.Code) = md5(B.Code)
```

> Note: I don't think this a particularly good solution as it requires a
> hash calculation on every value every time instead of using stored
> values, and it has a potential for collision with high row counts. I
> was using it on a small sample size with a one-off query and it worked
> well for my situation, so I wanted to throw it out there in case it
> helps others!