# Get exact value with letter case

Tags: mysql, sql

I executed this query:

```
SELECT name FROM `product` WHERE `name` like "product%"
```

It returns "product 01" and "Product 02". Check here second value has capital "**P**" which is unwanted in result.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: `.. LIKE BINARY 'product%'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `BINARY`

```
SELECT name FROM `product` WHERE BINARY `name`  like 'product%'
```