# Selecting all strings from database that starts with a lowercase letter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all strings in my database that starts with a lowercase letter with regexp, but for some reason it's selecting all the strings that starts with a uppercase letter too. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `allData` 
WHERE response REGEXP  '^[a-z]'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: As per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html): `REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings. `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [MySQL REGEXP manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.

You *may* therefore have some luck when using a binary string instead:

```
WHERE response REGEXP BINARY '^[a-z]'
```

Reasonably silly fiddle for demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eade/3

EDIT: As Ray says in the comments, you should probably use `[[:lower:]]` instead in order to work across all collations, e.g.

```
WHERE response REGEXP BINARY '^[[:lower:]]'
```

Comment: Don't you think `[[:lower:]]` is more general than `[a-z]` across character sets and collations ?

Comment: Characters that's not English alphabets?

Comment: @frosty Yep.  Might not be a concern for your particular use case now, but why not use the the built-in freebie and future protect your query?

Answer (score 2):

I would use mysql's Character Class Name to match in conjunction with `REGEXP BINARY` :

```
  WHERE response REGEXP BINARY  '^[[:lower:]]'
```

I don't know if `[a-z]` makes sense in every character set and collation, where as the character class name `[:lower:]` will always match all lower case alpha characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM allData
WHERE LOWER(LEFT(response, 1)) <> LEFT(response, 1)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

...however, this may be limited by your [MySQL character collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from alldata where lower(left(response,1)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS =left(response,1) and response is not null and response<>''
```