# How to search for the exact string value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

I got this code:

```
select * from locality WHERE name ="ISTASYON"
```

This works perfectly with mySQL. The problem comes, when I try to execute but result is incorrect

Result code:

```
28BAF9346A41E4E4E0501AAC4524363B    0       iSTASYON
402881a4523b52d201523b6c2afb4166    0       İSTASYON
402881a4523b52d201523b6c38b7417c    0       İSTASYON
402881a4523b52d201523baa9faf0092    0       İSTASYON
402881a4523b52d201523baab059009f    0       İSTASYON
402881a4523b52d201523baad01a00b7    0       İSTASYON
58441bc4c054447ebe1cddbfeef958b5    0       ISTASYON
fa7fb88d1d4c41feb497b08f42066c82    1   2016-04-19 09:53:41.000000  İSTASYON
```

My problem is that results contain ISTASYON, İSTASYON, ıSTASYON, iSTASYON  but i wanna only ISTASYON

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you using a case insensitive character set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

Comment: The 2nd answer with the most upvotes in the duplicate question is the simplest solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `COLLATE` or `BINARY` operator to force binary comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM locality WHERE name COLLATE utf8_bin = "ISTASYON"
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM locality WHERE BINARY name = "ISTASYON"
```

If you want the column always to be treated in this fashion, declare it with a binary collation.
See the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `select` query like this, I also use and it's helpful.

```
Select * from `users` where username COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE '%$email%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name LIKE 'i%', you get all column values that start with I or i.To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation.

```
col_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE 'i%'
col_name LIKE 'i%' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
col_name COLLATE latin1_bin LIKE 'i%'
col_name LIKE 'i%' COLLATE latin1_bin
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from locality WHERE BINARY name ="ISTASYON"

or

select * from locality WHERE name = BINARY "ISTASYON"

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A:**  This will be case-sensitive and accent sensitive:

It would be more efficient (after setup) to have the column be `utf8_bin` (or `utf8mb4_bin`.  `latin1` (and `latin1_bin`) will *not* suffice because of the Turkish characters.

The setup is

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN ... COLLATION utf8_bin ...;
```

Caution:  If you also want to do case folding and/or accent stripping with the same column(s) in other situations, this will hurt those situations.

**Plan B:**  This addresses the dotless ı and a few other Turkish idiosyncrasies.

`COLLATION utf8_turkish_ci` (or utf8mb4_turkish_ci) treats these equal: `I=ı`, then treats the following as different and later, but all equal: `i=Ì=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ`.  `Ü=ü` come after `U` and before `V`.  Similarly `Ğ=ğ` come after `G` and before `H`.  See [*utf8 collations*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) for more details.