# MYSQL detecting uppercase in Greek

Tags: mysql, utf-8, uppercase

In a MySQL database of ancient Greek words (collated in utf8mb4_unicode_ci) I am trying to detect which words are starting with a capital and in that case add the value 1 to a field include. I have tried several options using binary, e.g.

```
UPDATE word
SET include = 1
WHERE LEFT(`lemma`, 1) REGEXP BINARY '[Α-Ω]'
```

But also other solutions with UPPER etc. None works. Any ideas?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql

Comment: OK great, thanks: UPDATE word SET include = 1 WHERE BINARY LEFT(lemma, 1) = BINARY UPPER(LEFT(lemma,1)) solved the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time. You also have a preview pane right below the editor so you can see how changes look like before you publish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REGEXP` only works with bytes, so it is hit or miss on non-English letters.

MariaDB 10.0.5 has "pcre", so it does handle utf8 regexps.

`Α-Ω` is hex`CE91-CEA9`.

```
WHERE HEX(lemma) REGEXP '^CE'
```

Would check for starting with a Greek letter.  (It would catch all of `΄΅Ά·ΈΉΊΌΎΏΐΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰαβγδεζηθικλμνξο`.)

To restrict to just the capital letters, `Α-Ω` (as you requested):

```
WHERE HEX(LEFT(lemma, 1)) BETWEEN 'CE91' AND 'CEA9'
```

While I am at it, this checks for Greek *anywhere* in `lemma`:

```
WHERE HEX(lemma) REGEXP '^(..)*CE'
```

(Again assuming that longer list of letters, not just `Α-Ω`.)

(My comments apply to `CHARACTER SET utf8` or `utf8mb4`; any `COLLATION`.)