# Case Sensitive String Occurrence

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

I am using the following query to split column values. It's working for case insensitive scenario, but I want it to work with case sensitivity.

For example, in the string 'Oil is a product Ingredients are' if my searching keyword is 'ingredients' it should return `false` and should only return `true` if searching keyword is 'Ingredients'. Is there any function in mysql which allows this?

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, 'Ingredients', 1),
    if(LOCATE('Ingredients', description)>0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, 'Ingredients', -1), '')
FROM `product`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

Comment: See the second answer in the duplicate reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of mysql's **[LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)** function:

> This function is multibyte safe, and is case-sensitive only if at
>   least one argument is a binary string.

That is, you need to `cast`/`convert` your arguments to perform a case-sensitive match.

**For example:** If your first record is `Oil is a product Ingredients are...` and your second record is `Oil is a product ingredients are...` then the following query:

```
SELECT 
  LOCATE('ingredients', description) AS match_both_1,
  LOCATE('Ingredients', description) AS match_both_2,
  LOCATE(CAST('ingredients' AS BINARY), CAST(description AS BINARY)) AS match_second,
  LOCATE(CAST('Ingredients' AS BINARY), CAST(description AS BINARY)) AS match_first
FROM product
```

will give you the expected results:

```
| match_both_1 | match_both_2 | match_second | match_first |
|     18       |     18       |      0       |     18      |
|     18       |     18       |     18       |      0      |
```

See **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67704/5)**.