# Are WHERE clause in Mysql not case-sensitive?

Tags: mysql

is where clause not case-sensitive??

i tried using different versions of query for the table data:

```
username(TEXT)    pass(TEXT)

admin                admin
```

*The above table has only one entry*

```
SELECT pass FROM lbdb_user WHERE username = "Admin";

SELECT pass FROM lbdb_user WHERE username = "admiN";

SELECT pass FROM lbdb_user WHERE username = "admin   ";
```

all the above queries that i ran produced the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mysql collate, searching case sensitive**

Usually our mysql queries are not case sensitive. In order to query case sensitive, you can use the mysql COLLATE clause.
The collate clause lets you specify a collation, which basically is a set of rules for comparing characters in a given character set.

The suffixes ci, cs, bin of a collation stand for case insensitive, case sensitive and binary, respectively. A binary collation such as utf8_bin is case sensitive as well since it compares the characters based on their numeric values.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name like 'cRaZy' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```