# How can I search for upper and lower case letters with a full text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to find a record that is found in the search with both uppercase and lowercase letters.
At the moment, however, I have to search exactly as the data set is in the database. In this example with the capital letter "A".
When I search for "ahmed", MySQL cannot find any data

```
SELECT * from zusammen WHERE MATCH(concat_Names) AGAINST ('+Ahmed'  IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND zusammen.pep_sanktion = "pep" LIMIT 50;
```

I also tried with Natural Language Mode:

```
SELECT * from zusammen WHERE MATCH(concat_Names) AGAINST ('+Ahmed'  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND zusammen.pep_sanktion = "pep" LIMIT 50;
```

[image]

Comment: there is something called fuzzy search, try your luck with that

Comment: as examppöe https://gordonlesti.com/fuzzy-fulltext-search-with-mysql/ or https://sjhannah.com/blog/2014/11/03/using-soundex-and-mysql-full-text-search-for-fuzzy-matching/

Comment: If MySQL searches (including full text searches) are case sensitive or insensitive depends on how you defined your column (_ci or _cs), see. e.g. [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5629111). Can you check that/add that information?