# Show results exactly as stored in database

Tags: mysql

Our database has some terms included with different case (e.g. "apple" and "Apple").

When I try to get distinct values from the column (e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM products`) it ignores case and shows "apple" just once. (Same happens also if I use `GROUP BY`).

Is there a way to show all forms, without ignoring case?

We use MySQL 5.7

Comment: Check collations - there is case-independent collation somewhere. You may specify the collation in the query immediately: `SELECT DISTINCT fruit COLLATE '....' FROM products`

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5629121/10910692 .. maybe you'll find some hint

Comment: @Oyeme: yes, I could find a solution there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check collations - there is case-independent collation somewhere (in the table structure primarily).

You may specify the collation in the query immediately: `SELECT DISTINCT fruit COLLATE '....' FROM products`.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (fruit VARCHAR(16))
> SELECT 'apple' fruit UNION ALL
> SELECT 'banana' UNION ALL
> SELECT 'Apple';
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> | fruit  |
> | :----- |
> | apple  |
> | banana |
> | Apple  |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> | fruit  |
> | :----- |
> | apple  |
> | banana |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT fruit COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs' FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> | fruit COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs' |
> | :--------------------------------- |
> | apple                              |
> | banana                             |
> | Apple                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff18724d02a8229772cc30ef82432b92)*

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I get "SQL Error [1273] [HY000]: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs'"

Comment: @MátéJuhász Check `CREATE TABLE tablename`, look at column and table collation. Check `SHOW COLLATION` for the collations list available. Select the collation which is available and safe.

Comment: there is no case sensitive collations defined, and unfortunately I can't make any changes to the table.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Add `CREATE TABLE` output to the question text. Check `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'XXXXX_%'` where XXXXX is the first group before the underscore of the column collation (if it is `sql_` then take two groups) and add this into the question too.