# Select determined rows from mysql with determined word

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column`='System'
```

and this select 'SYSTEM' too. I want to select only and accurately  `` `column`='System' `` without 'SYSTEM'.

I'm try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP [[:<:]]'System'[[:>:]]
```

but again I have 'SYSTEM' too.

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE(column, 'SYSTEM', '')` to remove the word `SYSTEM` from the column.

Comment: You want a case sensitive comparison. `WHERE column LIKE 'System' COLLATE latin1_general_cs`. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql

Comment: I just want SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column`='System'  Start with capital letter and other small letters

Comment: This works for me:  SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE BINARY `column` = 'value'. Many thanks!