# mysql binary keyword issue with latin characters

Tags: php, mysql

Key in database:- !|%$&./()=?ì^

If I use below query:-

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE key='!|%$&./()=?ì^' AND Status='1'
```

This works fine.

But I am checking for case sensitive key(some users using case sensitive keys) with below query:-

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE BINARY key ='!|%$&./()=?ì^' AND Status='1'
```

This does not provide any data. On removing ì, this works.

key field collation: latin1_swedish_ci

Note:- I can not change collation because there are too much data in database.

What else I can use in place of **BINARY**.

Comment: Please dont store Plain Text Passwords on yor database. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: _Small Note just for fun_ I am pretty sure there are no lower case versions of any of those characters

Comment: I know but this is simple data

Comment: yes there is no lower case but in database there is for other users.

Comment: "This does not provide any data" - please share more details about this. Also, how is tihs related to PHP?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am using php and mysql. What type of data is missing here?

Comment: You're exposed here, this is bad. You should switch over to Bcrypt via `password_hash`. Normally this is annoying as you have to migrate from one password hash to another, but in your case it's actually pretty straightforward: You have the plaintext passwords.

Comment: @tadman, I know that. I said this is not important data.

Comment: As suggested by all of you, I have changed code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a best answer on the below link:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56283818/5346525

use convert as well as collate

New Query:-

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE key = convert('!|%$&./()=?ì^' using latin1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs AND Status='1'
```