# Why is SQL "WHERE" return value from table lowercase?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Sorry if my question is confusing.

Why does when I query

```sql
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = 'some-email@email.com' AND password = 'pass134';
```

I'm using a Node.js server with SQL, and when I use:

```js
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  var params = '?' + req.url.split('?').pop(); // "?email=test@test.net&pass=13456"
  const pass = (new URLSearchParams(params).get('pass')); // "13456"
  connection.query(`
  SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '${email}' AND password '${pass}';
  `, function(err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     if (typeof result[0].email != "undefined") {
       // User logged in successfully
     } else {
       // The email/password is incorrect
     }
  });
});
```

I try going to <kbd>https​://www.example.com/login?email=test@test.com&pass=Pass13456</kbd>, and it logs in.
But when the password is lowercase or uppercase, it still logs in.
I think this is the `WHERE` query not being specific enough.
How can I make SQL select value with WHERE as a specific value?

(e.g., `WHERE str = 'only equal to this string, not lowercase or uppercase';`)

Comment: MySQL is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing plaintext passwords in the DB in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks so much. Just what I was looking for!

Comment: I hope you never take this code into production as there are several severe flaws in your code. As Barmar mentioned, [you should never ever store passwords in plain text](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) in your database. They should always be hashed and preferably salted. Your query is also open to [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (use prepared statements!) and passwords should never be passed via the URL, because those are logged on the server and in the browser history and where not.

Comment: @Ivar that's just an example of my code. Obviously it's a security issue, I work in cybersecurity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So where clauses are case insensitive in mysql. To fix it, you can return the password from the query, hold that in node as a variable and then compare it (one solution)

Or you could use a binary comparison. I still need to test this but i believe you just add the “BINARY” keyword to your query. So like

SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = 'some-email@email.com' AND BINARY password = 'pass134';

Im writing this on my phone so i dont know if this is the best and i still need to test the binary solution

Comment: Thanks! I never knew SQL was case-insensitive.

Comment: SQL is generally case sensitive - this is an oddity of MySQL